# Why JFR skips event fields

Tags: java, performance, jvm-hotspot, jfr, jmc

I have a simple event:

```
@Name("trace.dbquery")
public class QueryJfrEvent extends Event{
    @Label("Event Name")
    public String eventName;
    
    @Label("Event Name2")
    public String eventName2;
    
    @Label("Event Name3")
    public String eventName3;
    
    @Label("timestamp")
    public long timestamp;  
}
```

and use it:

```
QueryJfrEvent qevent= new QueryJfrEvent();
if(qevent.isEnabled()){
    String name = span.name();
    System.out.println(" Check ---- " + name);
    
    qevent.eventName = name;
    qevent.eventName2 = name + "-bla-bla-bla";
    qevent.eventName3 = "test-test-test";
    qevent.timestamp = span.startTimestamp();
    qevent.commit;  
}
```

When I start JFR (jcmd PID JFR.start name=test disk=true settings=./jfr/test.jfc filename=./jfr/result.jfr duration=30s) the first time everything is fine.

All fields eventName/eventName2/eventName3 are presents.

For example:

```
jfr print --events trace.dbquery result.jfr
trace.dbquery {
    eventName = "SomeClassName"
    eventName2 = "SomeClassName-bla-bla-bla"
    eventName3 = "test-test-test"
    timestamp  =  1631023232432
}
```

But when I start JFR second time (the same JVM, without reboot)  as "jcmd PID JFR.start name=test disk=true settings=./jfr/test.jfc filename=./jfr/result2.jfr duration=30s"   fields eventName and
eventName2 empty but event3 is ok ""test-test-test""

```
jfr print --events trace.dbquery result2.jfr

trace.dbquery {
    eventName = N/A
    eventName2 = N/A    
    eventName3 = "test-test-test"
    timestamp  =  1631023234343
}
```

This code "System.out.println(" Check ---- " + name);" show correct value of name always.

I tried Linux  OpenJDK 11, 16 latest releases.

Comment: Can't reproduce. In my case, everything works as expected. Post the *complete* example, including the main class, test.jfc, and the exact commands to run. Also, which OS version and JDK builds do you use?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this issue in a  simple application.
I've been trying all day on an app with pure Java-core and with Spring Boot + Sleuth + Zipkin but this problem isn't reproducible at the same Linux host, OpenJDK and etc.

I will try further but I don't understand how my Spring Boot application can affect JFR inside logic.


I also empirically found out that during the second executing of the JFR.start, fields above 16 characters disappear. If String <= 16 symbols all is good.

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

Linux xxxxxx  3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 26 20:18:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: hhm. I don't understand all logic of JFR source but there are LIMIT = 16 [link] (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u-dev/blob/c1411113b396f468963a1deacc3b57ed366e735a/src/jdk.jfr/share/classes/jdk/jfr/internal/StringPool.java#L36 )

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug that results in missing string values if consecutive recordings are started, fixed in JDK 17 and backported to JDK 11.0.12.

The bug only occurs if a string is more than 16 characters, because then it may be cached. For more information, see:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8257621

Comment: Many thanks for the help but I've tried upgrade Java version but the issue is still alive: openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS

OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: I tested all day, tried to cut to 16 characters and still the custom event recording is extremely unstable. Cutting the lines to 16, everything seemed to be OK, but by adding one more field to my custom event, several events began to disappear from the dump JFR file altogether. Unfortunately, Custom Events in JFR is a very raw technology.

Comment: I wonder if you for some reason don't have the fix in the build/distro you are running.  Have you tried on JDK 17?